# Spring Security и валидный ввод

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Подскажите, Spring Security устанавливает какие-то ограничения на максимальную длину лога/пароля, если да то какие? И как их можно изменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Длинна пароля зависит от реализации, которую вы выбрали для шифрования. Они достаточно велики, чтобы беспокоиться об ограничении с верху.

Например, для стандартной реализации BCrypt есть лимит в 72 символа, после которого добавление новых символов не приводит к изменению генерируемого хэша.

Comment: те, нам неважно какой длины пароль и логин пользователя, достаточно установить длину поля в бд? А если юзер введёт логин 100 символов, а я установил разрешения 45, как мне проконтролировать это?

Comment: Если не делать никаких проверок, то при вводе имени более 100 символов вы получите ошибку при его создании. При логине такой пользователь не будет найден в бд. Огранить ввод на форме можно так `<input type="text" name="user" size="45">`

Comment: большое спасибо, отмечаю ваш ответ как правильный

Comment: только что проверил и увидел, что http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/size size - это ширина поля, а не количество допустимых символов.